# How to search for end-of-line hyphenated words in less(1)

Tags: man, search, less, pager, groff

Does `less` (or any other **lightweight** pager I could use as `$PAGER`) has such a feature?

For example, if I type `man bash` and then enter `/incorporates` it doesn't find the word, despite it being right there, in the second paragraph:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Bash  is  an  sh-compatible  command language interpreter that executes
       commands read from the standard input or from a file.  Bash also incor-
       porates useful features from the Korn and C shells (ksh and csh).
```

My djvu and pdf viewer "incorporates" such a feature, and probably other document viewers do too. (`pdftotext` simply re-joins the words, which means that `pdftotext file.pdf - | grep pattern` may still be more reliable than `pdfgrep`).

IIRC `info` (the GNU texinfo docs viewer) just doesn't hyphenate the words, in order to avoid this. While not directly actionable (I'm mostly using `less` with preformatted files), I would also be interested in any groff/mandoc options/tricks that could inhibit the end-of-line hyphenation.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're asking about `less` specifically or about `man` when the pager is `less` - however you may find the discussion here helpful: [How can I keep “man” from hyphenating items? MANWIDTH?](https://serverfault.com/questions/225892/how-can-i-keep-man-from-hyphenating-items-manwidth)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, `less` doesn't have this feature. This works with your PDF viewer because it searches through the original non-hyphenated text, not through the displayed text.

`less` is not aware of the original text. You must ask `man` to not hyphenate its output:

```
man --nh bash
```

Comment: No, pdf viewers join back hyphenated words when searching, there's no original non-hyphenated text. Believe me -- or check the source code e.g [poppler](https://github.com/freedesktop/poppler/blob/b7c400592b5b08d4759b6c45bdd4ff87af75fe46/poppler/TextOutputDev.cc#L1258) which is used by most Linux pdf viewers.

Comment: But `man --nh` is good to know, with the remarks that 1. it seems to only work with the `man` from Linux. 2. it still splits the compound words which are spelt with a "hard" hyphen -- like the "comma-separated" from the 2nd sentence in the "Brace Expansion" section of `bash` manpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the original `roff` source files, where the words will be joined together.

```
foo ()
{
    gunzip -c /usr/share/man/man$1/$2.$1.gz | less
}
```

Then, e.g.,

```
foo 7 groff
```